# Javascipt replacing exact numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, replaceall

am trying to replace numbers in an array but am facing an issue which am not really able to correctly manage regarding how to correctly target the just one data I really have to change.
I'll make an example to have more accuracy on describing it.
Imagine my data array look like that:

["data", "phone numbers", "address"]

I can change numbers via following script but my first problem is that it makes no differences between the number it find in columns, for example "phone numbers" from  "address" (at the moment am not using it, but should I include a ZIP code in the address it would be really be a problem)

Beside, my second and current problem with my script, is that obviosuly in the same "phone numnbers" a number may appear more times while I'd like to affect only the first block of the data - let's say to add/remove the country code (or even replace it with it's country vexillum) which I normally have like that "+1 0000000000" or "+54 0000000000"
So if a number is for example located in EU it really make this script useless: Spain is using "+34" while France "+33" and it wouldn't succeded in any case becouse it recognize only "+3" for both.

I've found some one else already facing this problems which seems to solved it wrapping the values inside a buondaries - for example like that "\b"constant"\b" - but either am wronging syntax either it does not really apply to my case. Others suggest to use forEach or Array.prototype.every which I failed to understand how to apply at this case.
Should you have other ideas about that am open to try it!

```
function phoneUPDATES(val)
                            {
                                                    
var i= 0; 
var array3 = val.value.split("\n"); 
for ( i = 0; i < array3.length; ++i) { 
                                        array3[i] = "+" + array3[i]; 
                                                                        } 

var arrayLINES = array3.join("\n"); 
const zero = "0";
const replaceZERO = "0";
const one = "1";
const replaceONE = "1";


const result0 = arrayLINES.replaceAll(zero, replaceZERO);
const result1 = result0.replaceAll(one, replaceONE);
const result2 = result1.replaceAll(two, replaceTWO);
const result3 = result2.replaceAll(thre, replaceTHREE);
const result4 = result3.replaceAll(four, replaceFOUR);
const result5 = result4.replaceAll(five, replaceFIVE);
const result6 = result5.replaceAll(six, replaceSIX);
const result7 = result6.replaceAll(seven, replaceSEVEN);
const result8 = result7.replaceAll(eight, replaceEIGHT);
const result9 = result8.replaceAll(nine, replaceNINE);
const result10 = result9.replaceAll(ten, replaceTEN);
const result11 = result10.replaceAll(eleven, replaceELEVEN);
```

Comment: What are you trying to change the numbers **to**? Can you give example inputs and outputs?

Comment: line 1 [name1, +1 800000000, Chicago- Illinois, USA]
line 2 [name2, +44 111111, Sheffield - England, UK]
line 3 [name3, +81 555555555, Nagoya - Japan]
....
....

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex replace, you could do something like `/(\+\d+ )/g` which will find a `+` followed by one or more digits followed by a space, and then you can strip out the match:

```js
const phoneNumbers = [, "+54 9876543210"]

console.log(phoneNumbers.map((num) => num.replaceAll(/(\+\d+ )/g, '')))
```

If you need to only target the second element in an array, i'd imagine your data looks like

```js
const data = [["data", "+1 1234567890, +1 5555555555", "address"], ["data", "+11 111111111, +23 23232323", "address"]];
 console.log(data.map((el) => {
     el[1] = el[1].replaceAll(/(\+\d+ )/g, '');
     return el;
 }))
```

Comment: you may think am joking at you but my code skills really are so poor, should I use a classic document.getElementById('div1').innerText = result11;  how could I show it there instead of trying a console log?

Comment: more over, how I would add a new line for all numbers to be replaced that way?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this almost is cheating but I really didn't thought it before and, by the  way does, not even actually solve the problems but jsut seems to work around it.
If I call the replacemente in decreasing order that problem just does not show up becouse condition of replacement involving higher numbers are matched before the smaller one.

but should some one suggest a complete "true code comply" solution is wellcome